# Transformation of probabilities brain teaser

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable. With no additional information, 
$$P(X>a) \not = P(X^2>a^2)$$
However, if we know $P(X<0) =0$ then we say the above holds. But we can claim regardless $$P(\sqrt{X} >\sqrt{a})=P(X>a) $$
since $P(\sqrt{X} <-\sqrt{a}) =0$ is implicit.

Under what conditions can we claim 
$$P(X>a) = P(X^r>a^r)$$
for $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{(+)}$? What about for $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{(-)}$? What about for $r=\frac{1}{r_0}, r_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Is $a$ positive, negative or any?

Comment: I do not think you can claim *regardless* that $P(\sqrt X > \sqrt a)$ is meaningful unless you know $X \ge 0$.  Meanwhile for your $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{(-)}$ question, consider $r=-1$